# Ubuntu doesnt seem to let me boot any CD apart from another Ubuntu CD

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I have organized the hierarchy in the BIOS and set the Internal CD/DVD drive to the top of the list.

I have four OS boot disks, *Windows XP*, *Windows 7*, *Open Solaris*, and *Ubuntu 12.04*(the same disk/OS that is currently installed).

I have tested each of these disks on a Windows laptop and each of them boot fine, however when I try to boot from each of these disks on my **Ubuntu 12.04** laptop, only the Ubuntu disk will be acknowledged before the OS system loads.(You can hear the disks spinning and being read but it seems like they are refused)

It seems like Ubuntu is holding my laptop to ransom(unless I provide a Ubuntu Disk), what do you suggest?

I am running a Compaq CQ58, Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks

Comment: Look at the boot order selection on the laptop; the BIOS is what determines boot from CD/DVD, not Ubuntu.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have said in my original post the BIOS order.

Comment: I assumed that was for the Windows laptop. Regardless, by the time Ubuntu loads the boot-option has been selected. Check your Ubuntu system options.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch When you say system options are these accessible once Ubuntu has loaded? Or before?(perhaps some other f1 button)? Thanks

Comment: Before. I don't know what kind of laptop you have. It might be <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>F-10</kbd>, it depends on the laptop.

Comment: [Compaq](http://science.opposingviews.com/enter-boot-menu-hp-compaq-presario-10339.html) makes a lot of laptops.

Comment: Might be an UEFI-related issue. See if there is some way to enable BIOS-compatibilty or CSM in the UEFI setup, and disable SecureBoot.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Just tried both keys, ESC goes to the same main blue/darkblue BIOS info/config/setup etc, I have been through nearly every possible option here. I also updated the bottom part of my original post with my laptop specifics.